# Using parameters within data.table column update by reference

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following data table and function which extracts a parameter and adds it as a column to a data table:

```
library(stringr)
library(data.table)

pq <- c("cm_mmc=MSN-_-Exact-_-BrandExact-_-CheddarCheese"
  ,"cm_mmc=Google-_-cheeseTypes-_-cheddar-_-cheesedelivered&gclid=CMXyy2D81MsCFcsW0w0dMVoPGw"
  ,"cm_mmc=MSN-_-worldcitiesuslocations-_-cheese-_-cheeseshops"
  ,"cm_mmc=MSN-_-worldcitiesuslocations-_-cheese-_-cheeseshops")


rq <- c("q=cheese&src=IE-SearchBox&FORM=IESR02",
                   "sa=L",
                   "q=london+cheese+shop&src=IE-TopResult&FORM=IETR02&pc=WCUG",
                   "q=london+cheese+shop&src=IE-TopResult&FORM=IETR02&pc=WCUG")

DT = data.table(page_urlquery = pq, refr_urlquery = rq)

# Extracts a paramater from the relevant query and adds it to the table as a column
extract_param <- function(dt, source = c("page_urlquery", "refr_urlquery"), param_name){
  source <- match.arg(source)
  regexp <- paste("(?i)", param_name, "=([^&]+)", sep="")
  col_name <- switch(source
                     ,"page_urlquery" = paste("url_", param_name, sep = "")
                     ,"refr_urlquery" = paste("ref_", param_name, sep = "")
  )

  dt[,(col_name):= str_match((source), regexp)[,2]]
}
```

However when I call the function as follows:

```
extract_param(DT, "page_urlquery", "cm_mmc")
```

It creates the column, but the contents are blank.  I think it's something wrong with the syntax in the data table (source) parameter.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the code inside function from

```
dt[,(col_name):= str_match((source), regexp)[,2]]
```

to

```
  dt[,(col_name):= str_match(get(source), regexp)[,2]]
```